# Boolean Matrix and circuits

Tags: digital-logic

What are Boolean matrices? How can one represent Digital Circuits using them?Please see if the 
following link helps?
http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/15/3/247.full.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. What goes around comes around.

A boolean matrix is a way of describing a set of functions on a group of input variables. In fact, most modern FPGAs implement this directly, where one function is implemented by a 4-, 5- or 6-input LUT (lookup table).

The matrix algebra allows you to compose arbitrary functions by combining functions you already have. The result is a new coefficient matrix that can be applied directly to the input variables.

The paper dates from 1971 and cites work that was done back in the 1950s. I don't know if anyone uses these techniques today.